# Can I use Remote Desktop Connection with Hyper-V instead of Virtual Machine Connection?

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have a hyper-v managed windows 10 VM.  When I start it, it connects the display to "Virtual Machine Connection" which, as far as I can see, allows no control over the display resolution.

The advice I'm reading is to use "Remote Desktop Connection" instead.

But when I attempt to attach with that I get "Your computer could not connect to another console session on the remote computer because you already have a console session in progress".

Is there some way of telling hyper-v to start RDC instead of VMC?  Or can I adjust the display setting somewhere in VMC I haven't yet found?

Comment: What version of Hyper-V/Host OS?  If you want more control over your VM, use the Enhanced Sesssion option on the VMC, under View.  Also, you will need to configure the VM for RDP, it is disabled by default.

Comment: Hi @essjae.  H-V Manager is at 10.0.17763.1, the host is W10 at 10.0.17763.503.  I've got Enhanced Session enabled already, but that doesn't seem to have any options regarding resolution.

Where do I enable RDP in Hyper-V Manager, please?

Comment: You'd enable RDP in the Windows 10 VM.  Either through Settings->System->Remote Desktop, or Control Panel->System->Remote Settings.  However, if enhances session is on, you can just drag the corner of the window and change the resolution.  If Enhanced Session is working correctly, you should get a prompt for initial screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to launch Hyper-V manager. The VM will need to be started (it can be paused, but not off). Do not connect to it using the 'Connect...' option under the actions pane on the right side (which itself just launches the Virtual Machine Connection executable.

[image: Don't use VMConnect.exe]

If the VM is running then you can connect to it using RDP. You will have had to enabled Remote Settings on the guest OS. Use the computer name of the guest OS in the Remote Desktop Connection modal's **Computer** field. If the VM has a domain name, you'll need to specify that as well as the user name in the **User Name** field.

[image: BizTalkDemo VM]